# The locus of $y$ where $B\otimes \mathfrak{m}_y$ is globally generated is open

Tags: algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

I got this question when reading Lazarsfeld's book "Positivity in algebraic geometry I". It's example 1.2.9. He claimed the following:

"Let $B$ be a globally generated line bundle on a complete variety $X$, then
$$U:=\{y\in X|B\otimes\mathfrak{m}_y\text{ is globally generated}\}$$
is an open subset of $X$."

His argument says that using Nakayama's lemma, we just need to prove the openness of the set
$$V:=\{y\in X| H^0(X,B)\rightarrow B\otimes \mathcal{O}_X/\mathfrak{m}_y^2\text{ is surjective}\}.$$

This makes some sense to me. The varieties in his book are over $\mathbb{C}$, and for any (closed) point $y$, one has $\mathcal{O}_X/\mathfrak{m}_y=\mathbb{C}$. So the surjectivity above implies that $H^0(X,B)$ surjects to $\mathfrak{m}_yB_y/\mathfrak{m}_y^2B_y$. Note that the map above is a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space homomorphism. However I'm not sure why we don't need to worry about points other than $y$. So that's my first confusion.

I am also confused about how he proved the openness of $V$. He considered the map
$$u:H^0(X,B)\otimes \mathcal{O}_X\rightarrow \mathcal{P}$$
where $\mathcal{P}$ is some sheaf whose fibers are $B\otimes \mathcal{O}_X/\mathfrak{m}_y^2$ for any $y$. He says $V$ is then just the locus where $u$ is surjective. But I thought after tensoring $\mathcal{O}_X$ with $H^0(X,B)$, it is surjective automatically, by globally generation of $B$. Did I miss something?

If not, how should I fix it?

Comment: "Let B be a globally generated line bundle on a complete variety X, then
$U:=\{ y∈X|B⊗m_y$ is globally generated$\}$ is an open subset of X." In order to get more response you should include a definition of the statement "$B\otimes \mathfrak{m}_y$ is globally generated".

Comment: @hm2020 Thanks for the comment! I mean globally generated as a sheaf here.

Answer (score 1):

For the first 'confusion':
to see $V$ is open implies $U$ is open. We simply claim that $V=U$.

Let $y\in U$ be a closed point. Let $m_y$ denote the ideal sheaf of $y$ in $X$. Now the global generation means that $$\oplus_{H^0(X, B\otimes m_y)}\mathcal{O}_X\to B\otimes m_y$$ is surjective.  In particular,
$$\oplus_{H^0(X, B\otimes m_y)}\mathcal{O}_X\to B\otimes m_y\to B\otimes \dfrac{m_y}{m_y^2}$$
is surjective.
Consider the cokernel $C$ of the map $$\phi:\oplus_{H^0(X, B)}\mathcal{O}_X\to B\otimes \mathcal{O}_X/m_y^2.$$ Now $m_yC=0$ as $y\in U$. Thus by Nakayama lemma, $C=0$. Thus, $y\in V.$ So $U\subseteq V.$

The converse is clear (as you have already noticed it) so $V\subseteq U$. So $V=U.$

Now openness of $V$:

Once there is a map
$$u:H^0(X, B)\otimes \mathcal{O}_X\to \mathcal{P}$$ $y\in V$ iff $u(y)$
is surjective.

As observed in the text, $Coker(u)$ is a coherent sheaf, so if its stalk at $y$ is 0, then it is 0 in a neighbourhood of $y$, implying that u restricted to a neighbourhood $V_y$ of $y$ is surjective.

Thus, for any $x\in V_y, u(x)=u|_{V_y}(x)$ is surjective.
So $V_y\subseteq V.$

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Dear Evans, thank you for the help! I think the map from $H^0(X,B)\rightarrow \mathfrak{m}_y B_y$ might be $H^0(X,B\otimes \mathfrak{m}_y)\rightarrow \mathfrak{m}_y B_y$, right? My first confusion is actually this: I know that the condition in the definition of $V$ implies that $H^0(X,B\otimes \mathfrak{m_y})$ generates the stalk at $y$. But I'm not sure why the other points would be automatically globally generated. Can you help me with this?

Comment: For my last confusion, I realized that I confused myself about the stalks and fibers! So it's all good on that one.

Comment: @ggttttll I think, there is some confusion about the meaning of '$B\otimes m_y$ is globally generated' as written in Lazarsfeld's book. In the standard practice, we define the notion of 'a line bundle $L$ on a scheme $X$ being globally generated as for any point $x\in X$, there is a global section $s$ of $L$ on $X$ such that its stalk $s_x$ in $L_x$ is non-zero. Here I am myself puzzled by what '$B\otimes m_y$ is globally generated' means. There is a natural map $H^0(X, B)\to B_y$ by taking a stalk at $y$ of a section. Also, I noticed that the book doesn't clarify the meaning as well.

Comment: I think in his proof of Theorem 1.2.8, he does mean $L^{\otimes m}\otimes \mathfrak{m}_y$ is globally generated for any point. But I don't know why he didn't even mention the global generation at other points.

Comment: @ggttttll $L^{\otimes m}\otimes m_y :=L_y^{\otimes m}\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{X, y}} m_y$ where $L_y$ is $\mathcal{O}_{X, y}$-module. It is not a sheaf on $X$.

Comment: I think $\mathfrak{m}_y$ is the ideal sheaf of the closed point $y$. Otherwise global generation makes no sense.

Comment: @ggttttll You are right. That must be the meaning of the notation. Also going back to your first comment, yes the map should be as you described. I corrected the notation in my answer.